# NodeJS Memory Leak when using VM to execute untrusted code

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, virtual-machine

I am using the NodeJS [VM Module](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) to run untrusted code safely. I have noticed a huge memory leak that takes about 10M of memory on each execution and does not release it. Eventually, my node process ends up using 500M+ of memory. After some digging, I traced the problem to the constant creation of VMs. To test my theory, I commented out the code that creates the VMs. Sure enough, the memory usage dropped dramatically. I then uncommented the code again and placed global.gc() calls strategically around the problem areas and ran node with the--expose-gc flag. This reduced my memory usage dramatically and retained the functionality.

*Is there a better way of cleaning up VMs after I am done using it?*

My next approach is the cache the vm containing the given unsafe code and reusing it if it I see the unsafe code again (Background:I am letting users write their own parsing function for blocks of text, thus, the unsafe code be executed frequently or executed once and never seen again).

Some reference code.

```
  async.each(items,function(i,cb){
            // Initialize context...
            var context = vm.createContext(init);

            // Execute untrusted code
            var captured = vm.runInContext(parse, context);

            // This dramatically improves the usage, but isn't 
            //   part of the standard API
            // global.gc();

            // Return Result via a callback
            cb(null,captured);
     });
```

Comment: Just link for node.js github issue for this https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6552

Comment: The VM module is not enough to run untrusted code. Try writing `while(true){}` in the untrusted part

Comment: This issue can now be tracked here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3113 the link to the /joyent repo is  now out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see this right this was fixed in `v5.9.0`, see [this PR](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5392). It appears that in those cases both `node` core maintainer nor programmers can do much - that we pretty much have to wait for a upstream fix in `v8`.

So no, you can't do anything more about it. Catching this bug was good though!